# Quais são as melhores praticas para colocar mongoDB em produção?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

Estou estudando node.js, e na maioria dos cursos o pessoal utiliza o mongoDB, gostei bastante de trabalhar com ele, muito simples e prático, porem tenho algumas dúvidas:

Hoje em dia, a maioria das hospedagens já suportam MongoDB?

Como saber se o projeto não é adequado para utilizar MongoDB?

Se não for, qual alternativa para utilizar com node.js? MySQL seria uma opção?

Obrigado!

Comment: Leia: http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1199 , http://zabuu.com.br/blog/radlive/nosql-ou-relacional-quando-e-como-usar/ ,

Comment: Legal vou ler aqui vlw brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo:
**Hoje em dia, a maioria das hospedagens já suportam MongoDB?**
*Sim, porem podemos utilizar o mongo Atlas(https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) com ele podemos utilizar free até um tamanho de 10Gb se não me engano*

**Como saber se o projeto não é adequado para utilizar MongoDB?**
O NoSQL é mais indicado para aqueles sistemas que tenham necessidades maiores de armazenamento e desempenho.

Se não for, qual alternativa para utilizar com node.js? MySQL seria uma opção?
Temos diversas Opções, o MySQL é uma delas mas temos temabem o Postgres, MariaDB, entre outros.